# Handling a VB6 event in C# - why does it only work sometimes?

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, event-handling, events

I have a VB6 application implemented as an ActiveX exe. 
I also have a C# application that interacts with the VB6 app via COM.

This all works fine except in one scenario.

If the VB6 app is kicked off from the C# app, everything is fine. If, however, the VB6 app is already running stand-alone, then although the COM interface still works, the C# event handlers never fire.

A (very simplified) extract of the code follows, names & GUIDs changed to protect the innocent.

VB6 app: myVB6App.cls (GlobalSingleUse)

```
Event myEvent()

public function RaiseMyEvent()
    RaiseEvent myEvent
end function
```

(partial) IDL generated from the built VB6 exe:

```
...
[
  uuid(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx),
  version(1.10),
  appobject
]
coclass myApp {
    [default] interface _myApp;
    [default, source] dispinterface __myApp;
};
...
[
  uuid(yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy),
  version(1.10),
  hidden,
  nonextensible
]
dispinterface __myApp {
    properties:
    methods:
        ...
        [id(0x00000005)]
        void myEvent();
        ...
};
...
```

C# app:

```
public class myAppInterface : IDisposable, ImyAppEvents
{
    public delegate void myEventDelegate();
    public event myEventDelegate myEventHandler;
    private object _myApp = null;
    private IConnectionPoint _connectionPoint;
    private int _sinkCookie;

    public myAppInterface()
    {
        _myApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("myVB6ProjectName.myApp"));
        Guid g = new Guid("yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy");
        connectionPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(ref g, out _connectionPoint);
        _connectionPoint.Advise(this, out _sinkCookie);
    }
    public void myEvent()
    {
        if (myEventHandler != null)
        {
            myEventHandler();
        }
    }
}

[ComImport, Guid("yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"), TypeLibType((short)4240)]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ImyAppEvents
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(5)]
        void myEvent();
}

public class myC#App
{
    private static myAppInterface _vb6App;
    public static myAppInterface VB6Application
    {
        get
        {
            if (_vb6App == null)
            {
                _vb6App = new myAppInterface();
                _vb6App.myEventHandler += new myAppInterface.myEventDelegate(DoSomething);
            }
            return _vb6App;
        }
    }
    static void DoSomething()
    {
        //code to actually handle the event
    }
}
```

As I say, if at the point that `Activator.CreateInstance` runs, the VB6 exe is not currently running, everything work as expected and the code in `DoSomething()` is executed when `myEvent` is fired in the VB6 app.

If the VB6 app is running stand-alone beforehand, the C# app can still control it via COM (methods not shown above for clarity) but the `DoSomething()` code never runs in response to `myEvent`.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that the problem lies in setting the sink for the event. At a quick guess I would say that you are creating a new instance of the VB component and assigning a new sink to the events generated by that instance rather than to the component already running.

The VB6 documentation states:

> Setting the Instancing property of a class to GlobalMultiUse or
> GlobalSingleUse allows client programs to use the properties and
> methods of the class as if they were global functions, but within the
> project where you defined the GlobalMultiUse class module, objects
> created from the class are not global.

The implication is that when you try to connect to a running instance, you're actually getting a new copy of the VB6 class, with it's own events, and NOT the already running class. Hence not receiving the events.

Comment: Even though the VB6 app is GlobalSingleUse?

Comment: Marking this as the answer due to the VB6 behaviour noted in my 2nd comment on MarkJ's similar answer.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [ChrisBD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577323/handling-a-vb6-event-in-c-why-does-it-only-work-sometimes/1577406#1577406), I think you are creating a new instance of the VB component. Have you tried `GlobalMultiUse` rather than `GlobalSingleUse`? The VB6 documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242107(VS.60).aspx):

> *SingleUse* allows other applications to create objects from the class, but every object of this class that a client creates starts a new instance of your component.

I would also set the project thread properties to thread pool with only one thread, to stop multiple threads being created within the VB6 exe. It [works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914628/getobject-and-vb6-activex-exe) in a similar situation.

Comment: D'oh! Sounds like I have the meaning of Multi- and Single-Use switched about in my head. I'll try it MultiUse and see how I go. The VB6 app isn't my baby, though, so there may be a good reason why it's set SingleUse (although I can't think of one).

Comment: Those names are **so** confusing. I have to look up the meaning every single time.